# NetBeans IDE 6.7.1 Ant Script variables

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, runtime, classpath

How do I get the location of rt.jar in my Ant script with NetBeans without editing my project.properties? ${java.home} is returning the location of the jre folder and not the jdk folder.

I know that I could easily add a value to project.properties but I don't want to. I also know that I could easily just modify the path whenever I switch computers but I would prefer not to do that either.

Edit: Maybe ${java.home} is the best solution and I should just fix my computers environment variables correctly.

Edit2: I just realized that java.home is not the same as JAVA_HOME. More information: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `JAVA_HOME` set? If so does it point on a JDK? From the Ant [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#advanced):

> When you need JDK functionality (such as for the javac task or the rmic task), then `tools.jar` must be added. The scripts supplied with Ant, in the `bin` directory, will add the required JDK classes automatically, if the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set.

Comment: JAVA_HOME isn't set in my environment details, but Ant has no problem compiling (using javac for instance). Ant works fine for everything, whats confusing is that my ${java.home} variable is set to "C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre" instead of "C:\Sun\SDK\jdk" which I'm assuming is the standard? I'm not new to Java as a language, but in terms of configuring it, etc I am. Is Java home supposed to point to the JDK or the JRE in the JDK? I re-installed Sun JDK with EE from Sun's website and it still didn't setup a JAVA_HOME environment, is that normal? Thanks

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. JAVA_HOME and java.home are completely different. I just found this out thanks to http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html - your message got me to re-think the problem again so I'm setting this as the answer. Thanks!